# Is there a way to stretch an image vertically just like stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

UIImage has a method called 'stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth' which scales an image horizontally without scaling the 'caps'.

Is there a way to do this vertically as well? Or even horizontal and vertically?

The SDK doesn't show me any method which might do this. Google doesn't give any help either, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong words.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you wish to *scale* or *stretch* an image, as the two are very different concepts.

Comment: aren't scaling and stretching synonyms?

Comment: True, but not in this context; stretching will usually cause some distortion to the base image (*in this case that's what you want*) whilst scaling is used to preserve the base image whilst increasing the size in an equal manner in all directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual method is

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

and it supports stretching (*not scaling, the two are different concepts*) in any direction.

If you want to stretch only vertically then set the `leftCapWidth` to zero, to stretch only horizontally then set the `topCapHeight` to zero. And to stretch in both directions set both appropriately.

Comment: aha! I keep getting confused by the very long method names and therefore missed that the second param actually handles the vertical scaling. great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to scale your UIImage to  your liking in both horizonal and vertical axes.

I put this method in an UIImage category. It simplifies the code.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```